# Make a webpage display more items on mouse hover at the bootom?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create something like this http://www.bcgurus.com/tutorials?page=8
when you hover to the bottom of the page more items appear and so on.
Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Do I get the qualification for doing your homework?

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me out !

Comment: no. do your own homework

Comment: Its not my home work.

Comment: So you are getting paid for this?

Comment: i know how to do this but this is homework or your job

Comment: google `infinite scroll ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well somethng like this really helped.

```
function yHandler () {
    var wrap = document. getElementById('wrap');
    var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if (y >= contentHeight) {
        wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
    }
 }

window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. Make a div at the bottom of the page. Lets say it's id is myDiv.
2. Add the following javascript code:

   ```
   $("#myDiv").mouseover(function(){

   contentLoadMethodHere();

   }
   ```

I will not supply you with the contentLoadMethodHere() method, but that is my solution to the problem.

Good luck.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Will try your solution

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the site!